# On Rails Active Record, how to get the method name generated for a given _id property?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

If I have, for example, a field `author_id` in my Book entity, and I add `belongs_to :author`, then the method `author` is created to access the object to which this id refers.
I can also use the following line to be a little more specific:

```
belongs_to :author, :primary_key => 'p_code', :foreign_key => 'writer_code'
```

And it still creates the author method. What I need is, having the `writer_code` field name, I need to get the generated `author` method name, or at leas the entity name provided. I'm sure Rails should store all these relations in a table somewhere, I just need to access it and find it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveRecord` determines most information dynamically; it does not store stuff in the DB.

You can inspect most information by using [ActiveRecord::Reflection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html)

For example you can try:

```
Book.reflect_on_association(:author)
```

This will return you an instance of `ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection` which encapsulates all information AR stores for this association, including an `@options` hash with keys such as `:foreign_key` and `:class_name` (if custom values have been provided).

If you don't know the name of the association you can reflect over all associations with the  [reflect_on_all_associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_all_associations) method. From there it should be a straight-forward collection and hash traversal: iterate through them and check for the `foreign_id` which you already know.

Comment: Ok, but what if I only have te foreign_key? I have no idea of the relation name (:author)... Is there a way to iterate over all associations or something like that?

Comment: `reflect_on_all_associations` doesn't set `:foreign_key` key in `@options` unless it was expressed in the Models association macro (e.g. unless you manually passed a `foreign_key` argument to your `belongs_to`).